# PDFs from *some* email sources are printing in mirror image

Tags: pdf, printing

I have alot of emailed invoices through to my business.

The vast majority of them print as intended. However, from 2 distinct suppliers they print in mirror image. They display as they should on the screen, but when printed come out flipped!

Its not always been the case (i cant pin-point the exact time, but sometime early this year), and Ive checked the settings on these particular PDF's when I print to make sure the mirror image checkbox is empty on the printer settings.

I just cant fathom out why its like this from just these 2 different suppliers! Any ideas?

---

update, its not actually mirror image as a whole, Ive just noticed its just the individual letters are back-to-front, theyre still in the same order, and the page layout is the same, just the letters are flipped!

Comment: What software are you using to print the PDFs? Can you reproduce this problem on another computer?

Comment: Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Comment: I use Foxit reader. It will print as intended if I send it via my phone to the printer, so must be a computer issue rather than a printer issue (or a problem embedded in the PDF itself)

Comment: Try another free PDF reader, such as Sumatra, https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html, and PDF XChange, https://portableapps.com/apps/office/pdf-xchange-portable , both of which I use often.